# substring of an entire column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe "df". In this dataframe I have multiple columns, one of which I have to substring.
Lets say the column name is "col".
I can run a "for" loop like below and substring the column:

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  df.iloc[i].col = df.iloc[i].col[:9]
```

But I wanted to know, if there is an option where I don't have to use a "for" loop, and do it directly using an attribute.I have huge amount of data, and if I do this, the data will take a very long time process.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Use the `str` accessor with square brackets:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str[:9]
```

Or [str.slice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.slice(0, 9)
```

Comment: This gives me the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning:`

Comment: great solution! but curious about which one is faster on large dataset... And how about compare to `df['col'] = [x[:9] for x in df['col']]`

Comment: You can use the suggested solution with

`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn' `

to get rid of the warning. Alternatively, you can look at these topics and lose a few minutes of your life:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379818/correct-way-to-set-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-avoid-settingwithcopywarnin)

Comment: Doesn't work for me : `val_data['col2'] = val_data['col1'].str[:4]`
>>  `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9 elements, new values have 8 elements. `

Answer (score 16):

In case the column isn't a string, use `astype` to convert it:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).str[:9]
```

Answer (score 12):

As one doesn't know exactly OP's dataframe, one can create one to be used as test.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': {0: '2020-12-08', 1: '2020-12-08', 2: '2020-12-08', 3: '2020-12-08', 4: '2020-12-08', 5: '2020-12-08', 6: '2020-12-08', 7: '2020-12-08', 8: '2020-12-08', 9: '2020-12-08'}})

[Out]:
          col
0  2020-12-08
1  2020-12-08
2  2020-12-08
3  2020-12-08
4  2020-12-08
5  2020-12-08
6  2020-12-08
7  2020-12-08
8  2020-12-08
9  2020-12-08
```

Assuming one wants to store the column in the same dataframe `df`, and that we want to keep only 4 characters, on a column called `col_substring`, there are various options one can do.

**Option 1**

Using [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#pandas-series-str)

```
df['col_substring'] = df['col'].str[:4]

[Out]:

          col col_substring
0  2020-12-08          2020
1  2020-12-08          2020
2  2020-12-08          2020
3  2020-12-08          2020
4  2020-12-08          2020
5  2020-12-08          2020
6  2020-12-08          2020
7  2020-12-08          2020
8  2020-12-08          2020
9  2020-12-08          2020
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`pandas.Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) as follows

```
df['col_substring'] = df['col'].str.slice(0, 4)

[Out]:

          col col_substring
0  2020-12-08          2020
1  2020-12-08          2020
2  2020-12-08          2020
3  2020-12-08          2020
4  2020-12-08          2020
5  2020-12-08          2020
6  2020-12-08          2020
7  2020-12-08          2020
8  2020-12-08          2020
9  2020-12-08          2020
```

or like this

```
df['col_substring'] = df['col'].str.slice(stop=4)
```

---

**Option 3**

Using a custom lambda function

```
df['col_substring'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])

[Out]:

          col col_substring
0  2020-12-08          2020
1  2020-12-08          2020
2  2020-12-08          2020
3  2020-12-08          2020
4  2020-12-08          2020
5  2020-12-08          2020
6  2020-12-08          2020
7  2020-12-08          2020
8  2020-12-08          2020
9  2020-12-08          2020
```

---

**Option 4**

Using a custom lambda function with a regular expression (with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))

```
import re

df['col_substring'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'^.{4}', x)[0])

[Out]:

          col col_substring
0  2020-12-08          2020
1  2020-12-08          2020
2  2020-12-08          2020
3  2020-12-08          2020
4  2020-12-08          2020
5  2020-12-08          2020
6  2020-12-08          2020
7  2020-12-08          2020
8  2020-12-08          2020
9  2020-12-08          2020
```

---

**Option 5**

Using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
df['col_substring'] = np.vectorize(lambda x: x[:4])(df['col'])

[Out]:

          col col_substring
0  2020-12-08          2020
1  2020-12-08          2020
2  2020-12-08          2020
3  2020-12-08          2020
4  2020-12-08          2020
5  2020-12-08          2020
6  2020-12-08          2020
7  2020-12-08          2020
8  2020-12-08          2020
9  2020-12-08          2020
```

---

**Note:**

- The ideal solution would depend on the use case, constraints, and the dataframe.

Comment: Option 3 combines nicely with `find`, `rfind` and other string methods that you'd typically combine with slicing.