# Correct way to set new column in pandas DataFrame to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create a new column in the netc df but i get the warning

```
netc["DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

whats the proper way to create a field in the newer version of Pandas to avoid getting the warning?

```
pd.__version__
Out[45]:
u'0.19.2+0.g825876c.dirty'
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As it says in the error, try using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer]` to create the new column.

```
netc.loc[:,"DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM.
```

### Notes

By the [Pandas Indexing Docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) your code should work.

```
netc["DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM
```

gets translated to

```
netc.__setitem__('DeltaAMPP', netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM)
```

Which should have predictable behaviour. The `SettingWithCopyWarning` is only there to warn users of unexpected behaviour during chained assignment (which is not what you're doing). However, as mentioned in the docs,

> Sometimes a `SettingWithCopy` warning will arise at times when there’s no obvious chained indexing going on. These are the bugs that `SettingWithCopy` is designed to catch! Pandas is probably trying to warn you that you’ve done this:

The docs then go on to give an example of when one might get that error even when it's not expected. So I can't tell why that's happening without more context.

Comment: I did `consistent_cnr.loc[:, 'num_weights'] = consistent_cnr.loc[:, 'name'].apply(apply_get_num_weights_biases).values` but kept getting this "warning." Had to suppress it with `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` right after import.

Comment: Now it gives me 2 warnings instead of one. Code: myframe.loc[:,'mynewcol'] = 1

Comment: If your dataframe was filtered or sliced, you need to reset the index before using this answer: `netc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`.
Otherwise the solution doesn't work, and you get the two warnings described in the other comments.

Comment: I was using a dataframe that was sliced and was getting all sorts of warnings. @kotchwane comment helped me figure it out.

Comment: I have been trying to use `setitem` operator (`from operator import setitem`) to assign values to a new column of a dataframe via a wrapper lambda function as `reduce(lambda k,o,v=value: setitem(k,o,v), path, dict)` where `path` is `[table_name, [new_column_name]]` and `dict` is a dictionary containing various datafrmaes,  but I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`.   Any ideas how to resolve this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 62):

Your example is incomplete, as it doesn't show where `netc` comes from. It is likely that netc itself is the product of slicing, and as such Pandas cannot make guarantees that it isn't a view or a copy.

For example, if you're doing this:

```py
netc = netb[netb["DeltaAMPP"] == 0]
netc["DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM
```

then Pandas wouldn't know if `netc` is a view or a copy. If it were a one-liner, it would effectively be like this:

```
netb[netb["DeltaAMPP"] == 0]["DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM
```

where you can see the double indexing more clearly.

If you want to make `netc` separate from `netb`, one possible remedy might be to force a copy in the first line (the `loc` is to make sure we're not copying two times), like:

```
netc = netb.loc[netb["DeltaAMPP"] == 0].copy()
```

If, on the other hand, you want to have `netb` modified with the new column, you may do:

```
netb.loc[netb["DeltaAMPP"] == 0, "DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM
```

Comment: Checking upstream to determine how the df was created is one of those frustrating subtleties I run into all the time. The advice in this post has helped me solve this issue more often than any other.

Comment: It also helped me tons to understand what is going on. I have been wondering why I see all these warnings while nothing was obvious at first sight; there are these implicit side effects that make the difference. Thanks.

Comment: If I want the last line's behavior, but don't have access to `netb` in this part of the code (think subfunction of subfunction), is there anything I can do without changing the architecture more drastically ?

Answer (score 18):

I had the `SettingWithCopyWarning`-issue, when assigning data to a DataFrame `df`, which was constructed by indexing.
Both commands

- `df['new_column'] = something`
- `df.loc[:, 'new_column'] = something`

did not work without the warning.
As soon as copying `df` ([DataFrame.copy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)) everything was fine.

In the code below, compare `df0 = df_test[df_test['a']>3]` and `df1 = df_test[df_test['a']>3].copy()`.
For `df0` both assignments throw the Warning. For `df1` both work fine.

```
>>> df_test
      a     b     c     d  e
0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0  0
1   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0  1
2   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  2
3  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  3
4  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  4
>>> df0 = df_test[df_test['a']>3]
>>> df1 = df_test[df_test['a']>3].copy()
>>> df0['e'] = np.arange(4)
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>>> df1['e'] = np.arange(4)
>>> df0.loc[2, 'a'] = 77
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1719: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_column(loc, value, pi)
>>> df1.loc[2, 'a'] = 77
>>> df0
      a     b     c     d  e
1   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0  0
2  77.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  1
3  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  2
4  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  3
>>> df1
      a     b     c     d  e
1   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0  0
2  77.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  1
3  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  2
4  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  3
```

By the way: It is recommended to read the docs about this issue (Link in Warning)

Comment: This helped me! Up in the code I made something like `df_1 = df_0["A", "B"]` and I was later creating columns in `df_1` (that is a slice, not a copy, of `df_0`). Changing the code to `df_1 = df_0.copy()` solved my issue!

Answer (score 13):

You need to reset_index when you will create column especially if you have filtered on specific values... then you don't need to use .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer]

```
netc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
netc["DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM
```

Then it should work :)

Comment: Actually, combining this reset of index with the accepted solution, solved the problem for me. So the second line of your answer should be `netc.loc[:,"DeltaAMPP"] = netc.LOAD_AM - netc.VPP12_AM.` See my comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380166/9450152).

Comment: Hi Kotchwane, 
I see what you mean and even  netc.loc[:,"DeltaAMPP"]  will not remove the warning.
Then what you need to do is to copy your dataframe to another one and the warning will disappear:
PS : to copy dataframe to another you should use : import copy  ==>
new_netc = copy.deepcopy(netc)
new_netc ["DeltaAMPP"] = new_netc.LOAD_AM - new_netc.VPP12_AM

Feel to put your feedback after you test it as I mention :)

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in other answers, there is a good chance that you have done some filtering on the data, else this warning should not have popped up (since your steps are correct).

Assuming you have done some filtering, you could try doing the following steps:

```
netc_copied = netc.copy()
netc.loc[:, "DeltaAMPP"] = netc_copied["LOAD_AM"] - netc_copied["VPP12_AM"]
```

Note that I have added a new column in the original DataFrame. You could do this in the copied DataFrame too.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to just use 'assign':

```
netc = netc.assign(DeltaAMPP=netc_copied['LOAD_AM']-netc_copied['VPP12_AM'])
```

Comment: According to the docs, `assign` returns a new data frame, so I suspect it does `.copy()` in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
netc.eval('DeltaAMPP = LOAD_AM - VPP12_AM', inplace = True)
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `netc`.

Answer (score -1):

you'll will still get error even after using .loc or .iloc for slicing, all you have to do is reset index after slicing

```
df.reset_index()
```