# Extract month from datetime column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, lambda

I have a DataFrame read from Excel with one of the columns of type DateTime.

```
sales_data=pandas.read_excel(r'Sample Sales Data.xlsx')
```

I was able to extract substrings from other columns using str.extract/lambda functions. But I was unable to process the column "Order Date"

The command `sales_data['Order Date']` gives the below output

[image]

As recommended in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505847/substring-of-an-entire-column-in-pandas-dataframe) StackOverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column), I tried with

```
sales_data['Order Date'].apply(lambda x:x.str.slice())
```

I got an error that : AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'str'
To check the type of the Order date column, I tried

```
sales_data['Order Date'].apply(lambda x:type(x))
```

I got the type datetime.datetime [image]
But when I tried the datetime operation

```
sales_data['Order Date'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime("m"))
```

I got the error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'
I got a similar error for the command

```
sales_data['Order Date'].apply(lambda x:x.dt.month)
```

Please suggest a method to extract month from the datetime object into another column without iterating through the DataFrame. I am not able to use datetime or int functions with this column since it is behaving as both a datetime and int column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `dt` accessor:

```
sales_data=pandas.read_excel(r'Sample Sales Data.xlsx', parse_dates=['Order Date'])
sales_data['Order Date'].dt.month
```

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> sales_data
            Order Date
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00
1  2016-03-28 22:00:00

>>> sales_data['month'] = sales_data['Order Date'].dt.month
>>> sales_data
           Order Date  month
0 2016-01-01 00:00:00      1
1 2016-03-28 22:00:00      3
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this and got an error with the to_datetime function. ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pd.to_datetime` to ensure your columns dtype is `datetime`. Then use `dt.month` to extract the month. You can also extract day and year by using `dt.day`, `dt.year` respectively.

```
import pandas as pd

sales_data = pd.read_excel(r'Sample Sales Data.xlsx')
sales_data['Order_Month'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_data['Order Date']).dt.month
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
`The sales_data['Order Date']` column had a mix of both date and int values due to some input data inaccuracy.
I found this since

```
sales_data['DateType']=sales_data['Order Date'].apply(lambda x:type(x))
sales_data['DateType'].unique()
```

returned `array([<class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'int'>], dtype=object)`
I cleaned this DataFrame by filtering out the values without the datetype as datetime.

```
type1=type(sales_data['DateType'][0])
new_df=sales_data[sales_data['DataType']==type1]
```

Now the new dataframe supports the date and string operations.

```
pd.to_datetime(new_df['Order Date']).dt.month
```

This can be assigned to other columns.