# Apply boolean mask with datetime to extract specific month with a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column ["DATE"].

I converted the column as a datetime object with  :

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
```

Now I want to extract only june month with a boolean mask, but I have an error :

```
df["DATE"].loc[ df["DATE"] == (datetime.strftime(df["DATE"], "%m") == "06") ]
```

The error :

```
descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Series'
```

Do you have any idea ? Is the boolean mask syntax wrong or am I missing something ?

I've looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375868/extract-month-from-datetime-column-in-pandas-dataframe) similar question in Stackoverflow but it does not help me because it's not about boolean mask but multiple steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
df[df["DATE"].dt.month == 6]
```

Your solution working with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
df[df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%m') == '06']
```

Comment: As simple as that !!! Many thanks !!!!!

Comment: For the second solution you added with series.dt.strftime, I still have an error : 'Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. But the first solution works fine ! :)

Comment: @Geoffrey - hmm, do you add `df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])` before `df[df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%m') == '06']` ?

Comment: Hehehe ! You're right, I did not. I tried with ```df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])``` and the second solution worked fine too. Many thanks !