# Delete characters on dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

```
ID Duration 
0   6-month
1   12-month
2   24-month
```

I want to delete '-month'. Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [substring of an entire column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505847/substring-of-an-entire-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Please describe further your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that month number comes before the '-month' in duration

You can use regex to extract the digits.

```
df['Duration']=df['Duration'].str.extract(r'(\d*)')
df
```

```
    ID  Duration
0    0       6
1    1      12
2    2      24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

```
df['Duration']= df['Duration'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('-month',''))
```